# why sql convert a number to '*' charachter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i run this query in SQL Server 2008

```
declare @a varchar(1)
select @a = 22
select @a
```

it's return this

```
*
```

why this query make this result ?

Comment: Which server? Sql Server or MySql / Oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are converting a 2 character number into a 1 character field.

**It won't fit.**

SQL is indicating the data is missing.  Otherwise, it would display just a `2` and you wouldn't know if this was the full value or not.

Comment: @CooLi3oY - because the options are either return a portion of what you entered, which could be misleading, or return a character to indicate that the value is incomplete.  It's safer to return the incomplete indicator.

Answer (score 3):

insufficient space was detected -

```
declare @a varchar(2)
select @a = 242
select @a
```

this will also do that

Answer (score 3):

Use following code:

```
declare @a varchar(2)
select @a = 22
select @a
```

Comment: +1 for right answer but it would help the OP if you also tell him why.